# How to convert from Riemann sum to integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

Im converting this to integral: But I need help!
$$\sum_{i=1}^4{\left(-2+i\frac12\right)^3*\frac12}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^4{\left(\frac{-13}2+\frac{47i}8\right)\frac12}$$

$$\Delta x=\frac{b-a}n=\frac12=\frac{b-\frac{-13}2}4\Rightarrow b=\frac{-9}2$$

$$x_i=a+i\Delta x \Rightarrow a=\frac{-13}2 , i\Delta x=\frac {47}8i$$

$$\int_{\frac{-13}2}^\frac{-9}2  ...\,dx$$

This is not the correct way. Or is it?
the problem is that $i\Delta x=\frac {47}8i$ is not equal to $\frac12$. What is the right way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, this is not correct. I'm not even rightly sure where the $$-\frac{13}2+\frac{47i}8$$ is coming from.

Instead, use $a=-2,\Delta x=\frac12.$

---

To give you more detail, first note that $$\left(-2+\frac12i\right)^3=-8+6i-\frac32i^2+\frac18i^3.$$

The $i$ in this case is a **stand-in for an integer**, ranging from $1$ to $4$. It is **not** the complex unit $i=\sqrt{-1}$. I see now where you were confused.

Using $a=-2$ and $\Delta x=\frac12$ as I recommended above allows us to rewrite the sum as $$\sum_{i=1}^4x_i^3\cdot\Delta x,$$ where $x_i=a+i\cdot\Delta x$. Since $$\frac12=\frac{b-(-2)}4=\frac{b+2}4=\frac{b}4+\frac12,$$ then $b=0$, so our Riemann sum roughly approximates $$\int_{-2}^0x^3\,dx.$$

Comment: That came from simplifying the cube.

Comment: How can a=2? There is the power of three in there. $(-2+i\frac12)^3$

Comment: Ah! I see what happened, now. See my updated answer.